# Why this code return exception?

Tags: android, database, nullpointerexception

Can someone tell me, why this code:

```
Boolean done = db.delete(ACCOUNTS_TABLE, KEY_ROWID, getIds(accounts)) > 0;
```

return this exception?

> 05-08 10:09:36.074: E/AndroidRuntime(1955): java.lang.NullPointerException

function return array of strings, so everything should be OK

### Solution

before delete a called close() on db

But now it return this exception:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteBindOrColumnIndexOutOfRangeException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x1eef920

Comment: Provide more code and stacktrace. As db may be null here.

Comment: Most likely, `db` is `null`, but it's not possible to say without seeing more code and full stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is indeed the problematic line referred to in the exception, it's almost certainly because `db` is a null reference, or possibly because `getIds` throws the exception.

It's a little difficult to tell without more information but, as a start, I'd be putting in something to dump the `db` variable out, either beforehaned or as part of an `try/catch` block around the call.

Comment: Thanks, before I call delete a closed db. But why next it return this exception? `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteBindOrColumnIndexOutOfRangeException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x1eef920` Ids from function I have in database.